# Join variable with string in a label plot

Tags: plotting, string-manipulation, labeling

I have a simple problem regarding writing in a plot label variable and numbers. I have checked in other forums, but I was not able to solve my problem.

I have this plot

```
y = 10;
Plot[Sin[3 x], {x, 0, 10 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "(" <> ToString[Superscript[10, y]] <> ")"}]
```

which produces this figure
[image]

I would like to obtain

[image]

How can I obtain this last plot?

Comment: `FrameLabel -> {"x", 10^ToString[y]}`

Comment: Try: `FrameLabel -> {"x", SuperscriptBox[10, y] // DisplayForm}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Superscript[10, 10] like:

y = 10;
Plot[Sin[3 x], {x, 0, 10 Pi}, Frame -> True,
FrameLabel -> {"x", Superscript[10, 10]}]

[image]